# xpath concatenate repeating element

Tags: xml, xpath

How can I concatenate a repeating field using xpath? For example I have the following xml:

```
<doc>
    <element>
        <repeating>A</repeating>
    </element>
    <element>
        <repeating>B</repeating>
    </element>
</doc>
```

How would it be possible to generate a string in the format A, B using xpath2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
string-join(/doc/element/repeating, ',')
```

we use [string-join(..)](https://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/how-to-use-string-join-operation-in-string-function-using-xp), you can make test [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)

Comment: Using Xalan, getting the error XPath selection failed. Expression: string-join(...) Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Could not find function: string-join

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22635328)

Comment: @JamesCoyle the question was about xpath - above xpath is valid and produce desired result string

Comment: You provided no explanation of your answer and seemed unsure it is even correct. That doesn't constitute a good answer and it seemed to me that this was more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @JamesCoyle your criticism is unfounded. The answer is an answer to the question and it is correct. Just because the author isn't 100% certain doesn't make it not-an-answer. (The OP saying the answer doesn't work is because the OP got the question wrong; they asked for an XPath 2.0 solution, but it looks like they're not using XPath 2.0)

Comment: @MDoe, you asked for an XPath 2.0 solution, but your comment says you are using Xalan, and Xalan does not support XPath 2.0. You need to switch to a processor that supports XPath 2.0 (e.g. Saxon). The problem can't be solved using XPath 1.0 on its own; you would need support from the host language (e.g. XSLT or Java).

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski The `/text()` in the answer is unnecessary, and generally considered bad practice.

Comment: @MichaelKay thanks for advice - I update answer. I encourage you to write your comment as answer about Xalan

Comment: @MichaelKay, You are correct. Based on your comment I ended up using the host language to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> Using Xalan, getting the error XPath selection failed. Expression:
>   string-join(...) Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException:
>   Could not find function: string-join

If white space only text nodes are preserved and there is no meaningful space in `repeating` element content, you could also use this **XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
translate(normalize-space(doc),' ',',')
```

Test in http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/8432615587db4dccf6dccdf48a6988f9

Output: `A,B`